# Send email (server side, not mailto) when html button is hit

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

I'm trying to send an email when an html button is hit. I want the email to just be sent in the background without affecting the html page view at all. Here's what I'm trying right now

FORM

```
<form action="" class="collapsed nav-form" data-parsley-validate="" id="nav_waitlist_form" method="post">

     <div class="form-group" id="nav_email_group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="join_waitlist_email">Email address</label> 
          <input class="form-control input-lg waitlist-email"data-parsley-error-message="!" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-type="email" id="nav_email_input" name="email" placeholder= "Enter email address" type="email">
     </div><button class="btn btn-lg btn-default nav-button" id="nav_waitlist_button" type="submit">Get In Touch With us</button>
</form>

<script type="text/jquery">
     $('#nav_waitlist_button').live('click', function() {
          $.get('sendmail.php?functionName=test&inputvar=something');
          return false;
     });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_REQUEST['functionName'] == 'test') {
mail('asbreckenridge@me.com', 'Some subject', 'somebody')
}
```

Comment: You need AJAX for that.

Comment: @Jonast92 - He's using AJAX, `$.get`

Comment: close that php mail   ';'

Comment: So what's not working with your code? What errors do you get?

Comment: FYI: mailto is server side too. What is the problem?

Comment: OK, added the `;` and changed it to button. I'm not sure the php script is even getting called though, is there like a 'php alert()' that can serve as an indicator that the php code is being run?
 Also, do I need to have a local server to run the php? Because I dont have one right now

Comment: Hehe.. yes you need a PHP server. Unless you send this to an online one, but it doesn't look that way.

Comment: @AndrewSB - if you also do a `printf` or an `echo` from inside the php, this will be the text that is returned to the javascript. You can then display the result of the ajax call - this will display the text you just `echo`ed or `printf`ed.

Comment: So I'd do `alert($.get('sendmail.php?functionName=test&inputvar=something'));` in the jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you're not using the form! If all you wanted is a button, you can use `button` and you would not need to add a whole form without any `form` elements.

You may want to capture the data you're sending to the server so that you can send that data. Just some few corrections:

JS - if you're using a modern version of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '#nav_waitlist_button', function() {
          $.get('sendmail.php?functionName=test&inputvar=something');
          return false;
     });
});
```

PHP - do not leave out the `semi-colon`:

```
if ($_REQUEST['functionName'] == 'test') {
     mail('asbreckenridge@me.com', 'Some subject', 'somebody');
}
```