# Have to send an email by clicking a button in Javascript / ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mailto

I have to send an business email template with dynamic population of Sender/Receiver information with images like ( logo ). Am using the below code with html ( mailto ) option. But am not able to insert images. Can i get any suggestion on how to insert an image in an email template. (Javascript / ReactJS )

```
var link = "mailto:" + email
+ "&subject=" + escape("Status update")
+ "&body=" + "Dear Customer," + newLine + newLine + body + newLine + 
"Thanks," ;
```

Thanks.,

Comment: Thanks., but i have tried this already. its not working for me. Do we have anyother suggestions.?

Comment: The conclusion of that other post, which I believe to be correct, is that you can't. If you want fancy e-mails your best bet would be to do that from the server side or through a service.

Comment: Could you please let me know in brief how to do that via server side..?? I dont have much idea about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331347/send-email-server-side-not-mailto-when-html-button-is-hit

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript. Images are also supported. [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The mailto link only supports text by spec.

[Sending mail from HTML page with image in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373737/sending-mail-from-html-page-with-image-in-the-body)